# Is there a specific reason to make view beans immutable?

Tags: java, model-view-controller, jsp, javabeans

A colleague recently suggested that we should make the model objects/beans passed from the service layer of application to the view immutable.

Are there any specific reasons to do this, any benefits or drawbacks? Where would this idea have come from?

Comment: I'm going to go ahead and shoot in the dark, but one reason may be that immutable objects are _threadsafe_.

Comment: @sthupahsmaht: While that is true, views aren't generally rendered with multiple threads. I suppose it's circumstantial.

Comment: @sthupahsmaht: If you're storing beans in the session that might be an issue, but as Jeremy says, requests generally only use one thread.

Answer (score 2):

Whether that's a good idea depends on the sole purpose. If it are pure view beans (and thus not really model beans), then making them immutable may indeed make sense. It is relatively easy: just remove the setters. This prevents the view from changing the bean by for example `<c:set>` and `<jsp:setProperty>`.

But all with all, I think this is unnecessarily exaggerated, unless you'd like to provide the view beans as a 3rd party API and prevent misconceptions/misuse this way. Or if you *really* need the setters, then they should probably not be made immutable at all.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, as you say, we need the setters to initially populate the values, otherwise we end up with bunch of mutator methods that don't play nice with the JSTL. The other alternative is to wrap them in immutable proxies after they've been created.

Answer (score 2):

The idea could have come from the concept of [Data Transfer Objects (DTO)](http://java.sun.com/blueprints/corej2eepatterns/Patterns/TransferObject.html). A DTO is meant as a transport object between server and client. The idea of making a DTO immutable is that it is meant to be read only; the client would translate the attributes of the DTO into its own representation, and do mutations on its own object.

The client would then send a DTO back to the server, and the server in turn would copy the DTO into its own internal representation, and perform mutations on that. This would allow the client and server to still bind to the message contract presented by the DTO, but not be bound to the contract when performing internal operations.

For example, a server sending a StockDTO object to a client may internally hold the stock information within a Business Flow object. The client, however, may take the StockDTO and add it to an internal trade object, viewed in a table.

This is the concept, but again, the design is completely up to you.

Answer (score 1):

If the beans are read-only inside the view, then there's nothing wrong with doing so. It may help prevent changing them in places you don't want them changed. However, you need to consider how you construct those objects, and if you intend on changing their state pre-view.